# How set the base url in the magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I have created cms pages for example "warranty". In the Url key field I entered 
"warranty". I am displaying the cms pages in the navigation menu. So the warranty page is also displaying there. When I am on the home page or any other cms page and click on the warranty page it works fine and redirects me to the page "http://example.com/magento/index.php/warranty" but when I am on the cart page which has the url "http://example.com/magento/index.php/checout/cart" and then click on the warranty page it redirects me to the path "http://example.com/magento/index.php/checout/cart/warranty" which is invalid and display 404 not found message.
What is the problem and how will I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
update core_config_data set value="unsecure.domain.com" where path="web/unsecure/host";
update core_config_data set value="secure.domain.com" where path="web/secure/host";
```

[Source](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/18660/#t65799).

Answer (score 0):

When in the CMS use [markup tags](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/cms/markup_tags) instead of plain URLs.

```
{{store url='warranty'}}
```